# Get result and state instead of just state from State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I have this code:
`runState (do { put 5; return 'X' }) 1` and the effect is: `('X',5)`. I would like to extract both result - `'X'` and current state - `5` in a do block, then do something with them. However when I use the `get` function like: `z <- get` it sets the result to the current state destroying the value `5`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `5` is the "result" of the monadic function, so you will need to catch that in the line before that, this is not "stored" somewhere.

Comment: How can I catch it?

Comment: Can you show the code that is not working the way you expect?

Comment: Just like `result <- stateMonad`, so the `stateMonad` "returns" a result (the unit type `()` is used if it does not return something (sensical)).

Comment: Do you want something like `runState (do { put 5; let result = 'X'; currState <- get; somefuncM currState result; return  result}) 1`?? It isn't very clear from your snipet. Can you provide a better example?

Comment: no, `get` does not destroy the state. with `let m = do { put 5; return 'X' }`, you can write `do { r <- m ; s <- get ; ... }` and you will have `r = 'X'` and `s = 5` inside `...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

```
foo = do
    x <- do
        put 5
        return 'X'
    five <- get
    {- ... whatever you want ... -}
```

In `whatever you want`, the variable `x` will be `'X'`, and the variable `five` will be `5`.